# How many chords of a circle with n points on it?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So, there are n points on a circle line all connected with each other building k chords. The question is, how many chords are there and how many intersection points are there. The goal is to find a combination equation to solve any case. I really don't know where to start...

Comment: What about doing the actual calculations with $\;n=1,2,3,4,5,6\;$ or so and trying to find some pattern? Latter, perhaps, you can construct a proof by induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an extension to Donantonio's comment you could do the first part in a process similar to this:

If you have a $n$ points on the circumference of a circle then you could denote these points by the list: $$\{A,B,C,...\}$$
Now to denote a chord you could write it like: $\{A,C\}$ to denote the chord that goes from $A$ to $C$. Now remembering that the number of combinations of length 2 we can select from a list of $n$ (since we don't care about order, $\{A,C\} \equiv \{C,A\}$) is denoted by: 
$$ n\choose 2$$

As a hint you could prove this by using induction and with this identity:
$$ {n\choose k}={n-1\choose k-1}+{n-1\choose k} $$

Answer (score 1):

To define a chord, you need to choose $2$ out of the $n$ points. To define an intersection, you need to choose intersecting chords, which means that the point is the intersection of the two diaonals of the quadrangle given by the endpoints of the two chords; so you have to choose $4$ out of $n$ points. (This assumes that the $n$ opints are in general position, i.e. no three chords meet; also that you do not count the given points as intersection of the chords ending there).